# How to locate PE header of MSI files

Tags: windows-installer, portable-executable

The [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) specification for image (`.exe`) and object files describes how to locate the start of the PE header.

However, I am trying to find the PE header of an MSI, and neither the approach for image nor the approach for object files seems to work. I am not even sure if an MSI has a PE header, but looking into the file with a hex editor indicates that it has one.

I've looked into the [Windows Installer Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-reference) but it does not seem to include detailed information about the structure of MSI files, so I guess it boils down to these questions:

- Do MSI files include a PE header similar to the one described above?
- How to locate the PE header?
- Is there a specification for MSI files similar to the one linked above?

Comment: I don't think that MSI format is an executable format. It is probably based on archive files.

Comment: @jtxkopt That is true, that is why I am not sure if an MSI even has a PE header. But looking into the file you can find the infamous `This program cannot be run in DOS mode.` string and something that at least resembles a PE header (starting with `PE..`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.msi files are not PE files. They're [structured storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage) data files processed by the Windows Installer service (msiexec.exe). Rob Mensching has a couple of blog posts providing an insider view:

- https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2003/11/25/inside-the-msi-file-format/
- https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2004/2/10/inside-the-msi-file-format-again/

You're probably seeing embedded PE files.